# How to mirror/flip the whole artboards in illustrator document at once?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform, reflection

I have 60 artboards in illustrator with different objects on them, some of the objects aren't centred. I am trying to reflect each individual object along the X-axis of its respective artboard. I have tried creating a box the size of the artboard and selecting the object and the box but still, the object mirrors in place rather than to the opposite side of the artboard.
The problem might be that all the objects are on the same layer but I am unsure. Any help would be appreciated.

[[image: 60 artboards with obejects1]
[image: B reflecting in place]

Here is the B reflecting in place.

Comment: Please show an example of one of the whole square art boards (for example that B like shape) where you show both what happens and what you would like to happen.

Answer (score 0):

you can not do that directly in illustrator
but there is a work around and it works perfectly!.

you must have the following software: Adobe Acrobat, [Pitstop pro](https://www.enfocus.com/en/pitstop-pro) acrobat plugin.

thefollowing steps is valid for any pdf document nedded to be mirrored / Filpped. in addition of many mas transformation.

here is the steps:

1. in Illustrator save your .ai file as .pdf
2. open the .pdf in Acrobat
3. from main menu choose pitstop pro > Global changes > pages > flip page content
4. Double click to adjust if you want your content filpped vertically or horizontaly
5. click run
6. Save your file
7. reopen the PDf result in Illustrator.

[image]

Comment: You dont need pitstop vanilla acrobat can do this. Just that the GUI is horrible.

Comment: Whatever, but Pitstop is very powerful, and I prefer it for that reason, This forgives its bad GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is good. You simply need to change the origin for the reflection using the **9-point Origin box**....

Default...

[image]

Change origin point...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can manually reflect each object relative to it's artboard center but it is a 2 step process for each artboard.

I would set each artboard to show it's center mark- go to the Artbaord Panel and from the dropdown menu in the upper right corner choose Artboard Options> Show center mark.

Then Select an object and choose the Reflect Tool (or press O on your keyboard) and Alt/Option click on the artboard center mark.

Choose Vertical and press OK- then do the same process again and choose Horizontal.

I do not have a way to do this to all your objects at the same time.

[image]

Comment: But you can do it one *column* at a time though. Just do as described here but with all objects from a column of artboards selected. Btw: I'm having a hard time making the "reflection center" snap to the center of an artboard. Is it just my snapping settings or doesn't it snap properly? One could always make a precisely positioned guide if all else fails. Or just draw a rectangle the width of an artboard and include that in the selection before reflecting.

Comment: @Wolff if you dont have alignment guides on then its harder to do.

Comment: @joojaa, I do have them on, but I can't seem to snap to center of artboards with guides or transformation centers. Works with paths though.